# Assigning new edges and faces to solidified mesh?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I've been trying my hand at basic blender modelling and I'm trying to create a box similar to the one above. However I'm having trouble creating the protruding parts, after i added thickness to my mesh through solidify, since both the inner and outer edge act as one. Can i divide them in to seperate edges and faces?

[image]

Comment: they look like 2 separate parts, so create 2 separate meshes?

Comment: The part to the left is just the lid. I'm talking about the right part and wanting to divide the highlighted edge in to individual edges and faces for the inner and outer. Right now the entire edge is just one single edge solidified.

Comment: You'll need to apply the solidify modifier before you can extrude part of the top face upwards.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with 2 separate meshes as they look like 2 separate parts in reali life, that said if you really want to do with one mesh, create a vertex group, assign a weight of 1 for the bottom, and a weight of 0.5 for the top, and choose the vertex group in the *Solidify* modifier:

[image]

[image]

[image]